# Access SQL- Filtering to ignore Null value in triple state box- Not Working

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, null

I'm trying to make a form that essentially acts as a filter with six checkboxes. What I would like is for it to return results that match the checkboxes ignoring Null values.

Here is what I have:

`SELECT * 
FROM ProfitAnalysisT
WHERE (MissingPPS= iif(Forms!ProfitAnalysisFilterF!PPSCK Is Null, "*",Forms!ProfitAnalysisFilterF!PPSCK));`

(PPSCK is the checkbox on the Form.)

My other thought was to do a nested iif()

`SELECT *
FROM ProfitAnalysisT
WHERE (MissingPPS=IIf([Forms]![ProfitAnalysisFilterF]![PPSCK]=TRUE,TRUE,IIf([Forms]![ProfitAnalysisFilterF]![PPSCK]=FALSE,FALSE,"*")));`

I'm tried this with TRUE/FALSE and -1/0. ALl of these result in an error saying it is either typed incorrectly or too complex to execute.

I'm flummoxed here! I'm a beginner, so I apologise if I missed something glaringly obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: a value test cannot = null.  Depending on your db you will have to use an "is not null" or a ifnull(value, '')='' or a 'case when'

Comment: Which db are you using (mySql, pgsql, mssql oracle... other)?

Comment: This is in MS Access

Comment: regarding the "= Null", I was using this because when I try to use "Is Not Null" or "Is Null", it comes back as too complex to execute.

Comment: a null can never equal anything. Null is an undefined constant . check this out it may help http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tricks-for-handling-null-values-in-microsoft-access/

Comment: I don't work in access so i can't help specifically with that db, but that article should get you started

Comment: I looked at that article at the beginning of my struggle with this, and apparently forgot the = part. I think I tried that because I was making a lot of tweaks to find something that didn't produce an error, and that was where I landed, oddly. I've edited my question- the issue then is, it says it is typed incorrectly or too complex to execute.

Comment: what are you expecting to see if nothing is "checked"?

Comment: I'm expecting that if nothing is checked, that is -1/FALSE, and will return only rows that have -1/FALSE in that particular column. I am expecting that if it is in a NULL state, it will return any value (So, TRUE/FALSE, it is a Boolean field)

Comment: can you show a few rows of sample data from your table it may help clarify the question or at least the column data types

Comment: Sorry, was trying to edit it in the post, but I can't seem to get a legible table in there... I'll try to describe it.

I have a table with a job number and 6 TRUE/FALSE columns.

I am trying to use the triple state checkboxes on the form to provide values for my query.  So, for instance, If I want the query to show me all Job number which have TRUE for column 1 and FALSE for column 2, regardless of their values in columns 3-6, I could select the checkbox for column 1 (TRUE), leave it blank for column 2 (FALSE) and leave the rest of them in the Null state.